# How does one iterate through an ArrayList during event handlers?

Tags: java, javafx

lets say you have a button.In this button, you have an ArrayList object called `one`that is supposed to be iterated through, to display all values once you click the button. My initial attempt:

```
btnFrw.setOnAction(e ->{           
              Iterator<String> iterator = one.iterator();
              while(iterator.hasNext()){                   
                StringTokenizer st =
                      new StringTokenizer(iterator.next(),",");
              txtID.setText(st.nextToken());
              txtG.setText(st.nextToken());
              txtBP.setText(st.nextToken());
              txtD.setText(st.nextToken());
              txtSP.setText(st.nextToken());
              txtCons.setText(st.nextToken());                                       
              }                

    });
```

But of course it wasn't that easy and on the first click it went through all of the strings to the last. How can iterate through the List properly?

Comment: "it went through all of the strings to the last. " Sounds like an iteration to me... Can you explain the problem a bit better ?

Comment: my plan was to return the next element in the iteration at the click of a button, but instead it it went to the last.

Comment: Well you do have a 'while' loop there so yes it will continue to the last, it will iterate on all of the data until it gets to the last, maybe I misunderstood you ?

Comment: with or without while loop it still wont go to the next element on click. I just need to know how to go to the next element per click.

Answer (score 2):

Create the `Iterator` outside of the click event:

```
 Iterator<String> iterator = one.iterator();
```

Then just modify your click event to use `if` instead of `while` for `hasNext()`:

```
btnFrw.setOnAction(e ->{           
              //Iterator<String> iterator = one.iterator();
              //while(iterator.hasNext()){  //use if instead of while
              if(iterator.hasNext()){                 
                StringTokenizer st =
                      new StringTokenizer(iterator.next(),",");
                txtID.setText(st.nextToken());
                txtG.setText(st.nextToken());
                txtBP.setText(st.nextToken());
                txtD.setText(st.nextToken());
                txtSP.setText(st.nextToken());
                txtCons.setText(st.nextToken());                                       
              }                

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand you correctly, you wont to change the button data per click by iterating on a list that sits inside the button(do correct me).

The problem with your code is as follows:
1. You are using a while loop so you will always end up at the last       element and not the next one.
2. Even if you wont use a loop you will still not get to the next element because you are not saving the state (the current iteration you are in).

How to fix this ?

Well you need to save a state, an index of your current place in the iteration.
after that you could do something like this:

```
btnFrw.setOnAction(e ->{           
              if(one.size() <= currentIndex){
                  currentIndex++;
                  // Change text here.
              }                

    });
```